# Different behaviour of eval " command \"$@\" ", "$@", and "$(echo $@)" when used as arguments

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, variable

I would like to pass multiple arguments to the Tor browser (firefox) programatically through a function arbitrarily entitled `tor`. This is so as to command `tor search terms` and voila! My search terms. When using these three variations,

```
~/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser -search "$(echo $@)"

eval "~/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser -search \"$@\""

~/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser -search "$@"
```

only the first two lines seem to perform identically. They result in a single Tor browser window searching for terms of arbitrary textual content. However, the third line results in one new search window per word.

### Why this behavior?

Let me clarify. I am not searching for workarounds but rather am just interested in an explanation regarding the bahviour.

Answer (score 2):

For the third version, you want `"$*"` not `"$@"`.

#### Explanation

To illustrate, let's set some positional arguments:

```
$ set -- arg1 arg2 arg3
```

Now, let's read them out with your `echo` formulation:

```
$ printf "%s\n" "$(echo $@)"
arg1 arg2 arg3
```

Let's see what `"$@"` does with them:

```
$ printf "%s\n" "$@"
arg1
arg2
arg3
```

The difference is that `"$@"` expands to three words while `"$(echo $@)"` expands to a single string.  If you want behavior like `"$(echo $@)"`, you should use `"$*"`:

```
$ printf "%s\n" "$*"
arg1 arg2 arg3
```

#### Documentation

From `man bash`:

`"$*"` produces a single string:

> "$*" is equivalent to "$1c$2c...", where c    is the first character of the value of the IFS variable.

By contrast, `man bash` states that `$@` produces a series of words:

> "$@"       is equivalent to "$1" "$2" ...

#### Using eval

Observe:

```
$ echo 'printf "%s\n" "' "$@" '"'
printf "%s\n" " arg1 arg2 arg3 "
```

When bash evaluates the `echo` command, `"$@"` expands to separate words.  `echo`, however, takes those separate words and combines them into one string. We saw this before when looking at `"$(echo $@)"`.   `eval` works similarly.  It makes one string out of all its arguments and it evaluates that string. Thus:

```
$ eval 'printf "%s\n" "' "$@" '"'
 arg1 arg2 arg3
```

This is also documented by `man bash`:

> **eval [arg ...]**
>   The args are read and concatenated together into a single command.    This command is then read and executed by the shell, ...

Answer (score 1):

Consider a simpler example to see the difference:

```
$ set "a b" c "d e"
$ printf "%s\n" "$@"
a b
c
d e
```

The preceding is what you *should* use; it's simple, easy to understand, and correct.

```
$ printf "%s\n" "$(echo $@)"
a b c d e
```

Here, `$@` first expands *unquoted* (the quotes surrounding the command substitution are separate and not yet applied), so it's equivalent to `$(echo a b c d e)`, and `printf` has one additional argument after the format string.

```
$ eval "printf \"%s\n\" \"$@\""
a b c d e
```

Here, `$@` is quoted, but the expansion produces 3 separate arguments to `eval` (`printf "%s\n" a b`, `c`, and `d e`), which are concatenated into a single command that produces the same output as number 2 above.